# Limitations in FDW code on passing List* metadata between GetForeignPlan() and BeginForeignScan()

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I'm writing an FDW for a non-SQL data source. Platform is Windows 10, C (MS Visual Studio), Postgresql 14. My FDW code is modeled after FDW example codes I have studied such as SQLite, JSON, CSV, File, DB2 and others. There is a common practice of storing metadata in a pg **List** as part of **GetForeignPlan()** and passing that via **fdw_private**. This list is then retrieved in **BeginForeignScan()** and made available for **IterateForeignScan()**.

My question is how to share a large amount of metadata across the **fdw_private** mechanism? Using the pg **List** macros, I have been unable to store and retrieve more than 5 **List** cells. I tried passing a single **List** cell with a JSON string containing all of my metadata, but the string becomes corrupted along the way.

```
List* mdList = NIL;
char feJSON[MAX_FESTATE_JSON_SIZE];
/// ... some code to format a JSON string into the feJSON buffer.
mdList = list_make1(makeString(feJSON));
return mdList;
```

I have also used **lappend()** to try and extend the **List** by more than 5 cells, but the additional cells' values are not maintained across the callbacks...

```
#define serializeInt(x) makeConst(INT4OID, -1, InvalidOid, 4, Int32GetDatum((int32)(x)), false, true)

result = list_make5(makeInteger(feState->start), makeInteger(feState->rows), makeString(feState->ltName), makeString(feState->ftName), makeInteger(feState->myTable->npgcols));
result = lappend(result, serializeInt(feState->myTable->ncols));
```

There is a hint in the pg source [plannodes.h](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/plannodes_8h_source.html#l00665) suggesting the use of **bytea** (byte array?) as an alternative to the pg **List** structure, but I'm not finding any examples for that, so far.

I'm suspecting certain characters in JSON strings may be part of the issue, but I also found that...

```
#define MAX_FESTATE_JSON_SIZE 2048
List* serializeMetadata(...)
{
  List* mdList = NIL;
  /// ...stuff...
    char smokeTest[MAX_FESTATE_JSON_SIZE + 1];
    memset(smokeTest, 'X', MAX_FESTATE_JSON_SIZE);
    smokeTest[MAX_FESTATE_JSON_SIZE] = '\0';
  mdList = list_make1(makeString(smokeTest));
  return mdList;
}
```

...revealed some truncation of the **List** as a return value (but it's a pointer!?). So I'm not sure if casting a bytea* as a List* will help, but that's where I'm headed.

Suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: A list should work fine. You don't describe what `serializeInt` does, but I hope it returns a `datum *`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I updated the Q showing the definition of `serializeInt()`. I used it in the same way as the DB2 FDW. I'm wondering if the issue is build related since I can ^C ^V existing FDW codes and get broken results.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I replaced `serializeInt()` with `makeInteger()` and the subsequent `lappend()` appears to work now. I'm going to experiment further with codes based on something other than the DB2 FDW.

Comment: Funny, that's a copy of my code. Both should work; but an `Integer` is different from a `Const`. Perhaps the error is in the code that extracts the values from the list, in that you cast it to something wrong.